# Is there a blog engine which can work directly with posts written with LaTeX markup?

Tags: markup

I several times have searched without success for a blogging engine which accepts posts written in LaTeX markup.  For this application, I have no interest in the ability of LaTeX to typeset  mathematical formulae, nor is it necessary that the engine handle every LaTeX construct available in the article class; I would be happy to be constrained to a small subset of LaTeX commands.

The basic problem is that I use LaTeX for EVERYTHING written.  Blogging should be natural and easy.  I find it natural and MUCH easier to write in LaTeX markup, rather than (1) to fool around with someone's ill-conceived and childish notion of a "simplified" markup language, or (2) to write in LaTeX and then convert the post to a markup language which a blogging engine is able to read.

Comment: sure, there is `staticsite` extension for TeX4ht that enables to produce content for static site generators. see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/506587/2891

Comment: This news, along with the news that TeX4ht is alive and well, is well-received.  I have no interest in dynamic sites, and I really need a blog, in addition to the main web site.  I am surprised that this is the first time I recall hearing of the extension.

Comment: The extension is relatively new. I don't know if anybody uses it in practice. I plan to use it for my blog, but I plan to create my blog for at least 6 years, so it may take some time :)

Comment: I printed out and read the discussion, but I do not think that I understand enough of it to get a blog running.  And which static site generator needs to be running in www?  After looking at several engines, Pelican seemed to me to be one of the best.  Of course, the blog would be hosted on a remote shared host, and that complicates matters, unless the engine is WordPress.

Comment: you can use any static generator that supports the YAML header, there are several for almost every programming language.  I use Lettersmith for Lua, but only because Lua is my favourite language. I know Jekyll works, Hugo, Eleventy, etc. I can see that Pelican doesn't use the YAML header, but there are plugins that should add the support: https://github.com/noirbizarre/pelican-frontmark.

Comment: The site generator should read files in `build` directory, it will then generate HTML site in the `www` directory. This needs to be configured in the generator configuration, it should be possible in every one. Files from the `www` dir then can be served to the server, using `rsync`, `git`, `ftp`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Now I must take another look at Jekyll vs. Hugo vs. whatever. RSS or Atom would be nice, but not essential.   Even keywords are not essential.  I need an approach to blogging which is simple to use.

Comment: as I said, most static site generators are similar. It is just necessary to do the first configuration, publishing should be easy then. The good thing about Jekyll is that it is built in on Github, so you can just push the HTML files generated by TeX4ht and the site can be built automatically. See https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/setting-up-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll

Comment: it seems that stackexchange does not like to be used as a maillist.  Is there an active tex4ht maillist, and can this thread be moved there? or has tex4ht become so well-established that there is no need for a list?

Comment: @russ -- There's a mailing list `tex4ht@tug.org`.  I have no idea how active it is, but it's listed at https://tug.org/mailman/listinfo

Answer (score 0):

[Functor Network](https://www.functor.network) is the blogging engine you are seeking, and you can even expect more from it. It accepts posts written in LaTeX markup and support the cross-reference feature you wants. Moreover, it supports almost all latex commands and latex packages. Here is its [latex editor demo](https://www.functor.network/help/editor?format=tex).