# Is there persons who uses the latex for general writing?

Tags: markdown

I mean not math related things, just a diary, blog post, memo, etc.

I saw [Blogging in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/506578/blogging-in-latex)

And..., I think markdown is enough to general writing, but I also wanna write things with latex to learn latex.

Please let me know why do you use latex over markdown if you use latex for general writing.

Comment: related [Why should I use LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1756/why-should-i-use-latex)

Comment: I'm not sure if the question is really on-topic, so I just answer here in comments: I use LaTeX for general writing over markdown simply because I don't know markdown.

Comment: Whoa! You seems like a genius to me! LaTeX is way more harder than markdown in my experience.

Comment: @HeathKim latex allows you to control every aspect of the formatting, so most of the questions and answers on this site for example might be compared with writing a markdown processor, that is more complicated than simply writing a markdown document.  For the range of documents that are expressable in markdown I would not say latex is any more complicated. `\textit{foo}` is not the same as `_foo_` but it is not more complicated.