# Empty html with Blogging in LaTeX

Tags: html, htlatex, make4ht

As the title suggests, this is a follow up of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/506578/140456).
I'm following [Michal's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/506587/140456), I have created the same structure suggested in the answer, created the `.make4ht` file and the same `hello.tex`file, but when I run `make4ht -um publish hello.tex` I recive the following message in terminal

```
[STATUS]  make4ht: Conversion started
[STATUS]  make4ht: Input file: hello.tex
removing maketitle
sh: 1: tidy: not found
...exmf-dist/scripts/make4ht/filters/make4ht-staticsite.lua:86: attempt to index a nil value (local 'head')
```

and the result is an empty `date-hello.html` file.

Since I'm completely new with all of that I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: it is better to make your question self contained. Do it ask people to chase links trying to find what your `hello.tex` file is. Adding the links to the earlier questions is good. But the question itself should contain all material needed to run it.

Comment: @Nasser Thanks for the suggestion! I’ll add the necessary information in a moment.

Comment: You need to eiher disable the tid extension, or install HTML Tidy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to tell without a MWE, but if you use exact code from the question you linked, I would say that the problem is a bug in the `tidy` extension for `make4ht`. It didn't check if the string returned by the `tidy` command is not empty.

We can see that the problem is with `tidy` from this message:

```
sh: 1: tidy: not found
...exmf-dist/scripts/make4ht/filters/make4ht-staticsite.lua:86: attempt to index a nil value (local 'head')
```

You can either [install Tidy](https://www.html-tidy.org/), or disable it in the `.make4ht` configuration file:

```lua
local outdir = os.getenv "kodymirus_root" or "out"
local domfilter = require "make4ht-domfilter"

-- remove the \maketitle environment from the HTML file, title will be inserted in the template
local domprocess = domfilter{function(dom)
  local maketitles = dom:query_selector(".maketitle")
  for _, el in ipairs(maketitles) do
    print "removing maketitle"
    el:remove_node()
  end
  return dom
end}

filter_settings "staticsite" {
  site_root = outdir, 
  map = {
    [".css$"] = "css/"
  },
  header = {
     layout="post",
     date = function(parameters)
       return os.date("!%Y-%m-%d %T", parameters.time)
     end
  }
}

Make:enable_extension "common_domfilters"
if mode=="draft" then
  Make:htlatex {}
elseif mode=="publish" then
  -- Make:htlatex {}
  Make:match("html$", domprocess)
  -- Make:enable_extension "tidy"
  Make:htlatex {}
else
  Make:htlatex {}
  Make:htlatex {}
  Make:htlatex {}
end
```

If you are interested in blogging with TeX4ht, see also [this blog](https://www.kodymirus.cz/testblog/) that is generated from LaTeX sources automatically by Github. [Here are the sources](https://github.com/michal-h21/testblog).