# Commutative diagrams for a blog

Tags: overleaf, plot

I have been lately dabbling with the thought of relaunching my math blog. I want to cover category theoretical related topics, and thous would like to be able to plot.

I found [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30580/what-are-your-options-to-draw-commutative-diagrams-on-mse) blogpost, however this is not satisfying. Other than compiling on Overleaf, screenshoting and pasting, I can't really think of a workaround.

How can I do that? Is there some Web engine I can use?

Thanks!

Comment: You may consider appropriate blog platform, e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/696935/42803

Comment: You can do just the image using standalonw class and paste the entire PDF (assuming Overleaf will give you a PDF).